# What does it mean if the dd clock is ticking very slowly (every 12s only)?

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I have an Intenso external 1TB 2,5" HDD here. It is somehow faulty (disconnects randomly on Windows) so I decided to run this command to check it:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null bs=4M status=progress
```

The output when running looks like this:

```
715099471872 Bytes (715 GB, 666 GiB) kopiert, 16115 s, 44,4 MB/s
```

Besides that 44,4 MB/s is too slow for an USB3 disk the strange thing is that the clock is ticking every 12s only. ("16115 s" is the dd clock.) When running the same command on a healthy disk it ticks every second.

I tried `strace` to see why it is blocking so long but it seems to read the disk by memory mapping so I cannot see anything.

It's also not possible that the disk simply blocks 12s when reading. Because the speed is 44,4 MB/s and the block size is 4 MB. So dd has 11 chances per second to update the clock.

So what is happening here exactly?

(I am not interested in what is wrong with the disk but instead I want to know why the dd clock is ticking so slowly. So I hope I'm right on SE Unix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` can only update its display between individual copy operations; when you real GNU coreutils' `dd.c`, you'll find the main `while` loop simplifying to:

```
int dd_copy() {
  // some setup
  while(true) {
    if(progress_reporting_enabled && minimum_time_passed) {
      print_xfer_stats();
    }
    copy_a_block;
  }
}
```

If copying blocks takes 12 seconds each iteration, you *can't* get a visual update.

Honestly, `dd` is simply not the program you want to use (in surprisingly many cases, but especially) here.

```bash
pv /dev/sdb > /dev/null
```

will probably be more illuminating; if you happen to really want to read in 4MB-blocks (why? Your hard drive probably has 1024 B blocks, and USB transfers are much smaller, so larger transfers have very diminishing returns in speed),

```bash
pv -B 4M /dev/sdb > /dev/null
```

(I know you said you don't care about the disk, and your question is why `dd` behaves that way, but for future readers experimenting with their hard drive that misbehaves:)
But, **from a higher-up perspective**: you're dealing with a hard drive that's breaking down. I'd recommend you use it as little as possible, aside from making a backup of its contents.

Comment: But if dd copies a block every 12s then the speed would be 4 MB/12s = 0,33 MB/s but it is 44,4 MB/s. So this cannot be the case.

Comment: @zomega it *is* the case (see the source code), because the underlying kernel buffer readahead copies way more after the first block has been copied, but control is already passed back to the userland process; then that userland process (dd) can happily work with the much data that are already prefetched, up to the point where that prefetching stalls due to whatever your hard drive does.

Comment: Did you mean `/dev/null`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yeah… dunno how that typo ended up in there.

Comment: I now tried pv (without -B option) and it is also ticking in 12s steps.

Comment: yep, then something blocks your device for 12 seconds, periodically. It would sound like firmware resetting something due to a hardware fault, probably.